# Not able to resize doughnut chart build with angular js

Tags: angularjs, canvas, charts, highcharts

My issue is that I am not able to reduce the size of angular doughnut chart. 
I am using chart.js as dependency in angular module and using canvas of doughnut in markup. With height and width attribute its size doesn't varies much. Please find here my canvas code-

```
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" height=".00001" width=".00001"
```

chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">

I have created plunker here-
https://plnkr.co/edit/Mf5UuyptuhS0JAkrpWXe?p=preview

my problem is that the chart size is not reducing much and it is coming on the whole page, how can I reduce the size of my chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `div` like this

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px;">
     <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>  
</div>
```

This works on your plunker.

Comment: In addition to this comment, you can use max-width and max-height to have option of reducing size of your pie: https://plnkr.co/edit/W4EdNPzTUilaJMxXBayY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this -

`<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
    responsive = true height="50px" width="100px"
  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">`

working fine for me.

Comment: It's still responsive.

Comment: Yes. If you don't want then skip responsive = true.